# How would I adjust this method to overwrite a large buffer in a binary file?

Tags: c#, methods, buffer

Edited in a attempt to correct and clarify my original request.  Sorry this is confusing.

I'm trying to use this method I found on stack overflow to search for 2 characters "YY" of a 24 character string that is compiled in "testBin.exe".  I would like to overwrite "YY" and any following data with string that is smaller or the same length.  testBin.exe executes fine if the search string and replacement string are the same length, if the search string is smaller then 24 characters it's value in is overwritten and the replacement string is appended to the original string corrupting the binary.

I would like the replacement string to overwrite data from the first instance the search string is found.  I realize this is destructive so I have padded my executable with a larger string as a placeholder.  So long as the total string length remains the same the program will execute as normal.  I've played around with this method for couple of days and I'm thinking that there is something I'm not seeing in Buffer.BlockCopy and I just need to somehow leave off the length of  search string so it will overwrite the whole string. Any assistance is appreciated.

[Here is a hex view of the unaltered testBin.exe with 24 Y characters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlKmz.png)

[This is a one-for-one replacement of characters if searchString and replacementString are the same length.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqGaW.png)

[If I only search for "YY" and not the 24 char "YY" string only "YY" is overwritten.  The replacementString is added and now I have 46 characters.  I would like to search for the first 2 char and overwrite it with the replacementString resulting in 24 total chars.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8lHu.png)

Reference: [How can I replace a unicode string in a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062565/how-can-i-replace-a-unicode-string-in-a-binary-file)

My method:

```
    // Works fine when searchString and replacementString are the 
    // same length.
    static string searchString = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";
    static string replacementString = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";

    // Corrupts the binary when the searchString is a lesser length than 
    // replacementString. 
    static string searchString = "YY";
    static string replacementString = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";

    public static void BinaryWriter(object state)
    {

        byte[] fileName = File.ReadAllBytes(@"testBin.exe"),
        oldBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(searchString),
        newBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(replacementString);

        int index = IndexOfBytes(fileName, oldBytes);

        if (index < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        byte[] newFileBytes = 
            new byte[fileName.Length + newBytes.Length - oldBytes.Length];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(fileName, 0, newFileBytes, 0, index);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(newBytes, 0, newFileBytes, index, newBytes.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(fileName, index + oldBytes.Length, newFileBytes, 
            index + newBytes.Length, fileName.Length - index - oldBytes.Length);

        File.WriteAllBytes(@"new_testBin.exe", newFileBytes);

        int IndexOfBytes(byte[] searchBuffer, byte[] bytesToFind)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < searchBuffer.Length - bytesToFind.Length; i++)
            {
                bool success = true;

                for (int j = 0; j < bytesToFind.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (searchBuffer[i + j] != bytesToFind[j])
                    {
                        success = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (success)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do that?
What are you expecting after replace? - to work as executable? - because it will not work!

Your method use a `ReplaceTextInFile` but the .exe file is a structured file, not a simple binary raw characters. Some key positions are marked.

Example:
offset 0: - command
offset 100: some code
offset 200: your text
offset 220: other text

Now if, you replace "your text" at the given offset, with a longer character, example with a length of 40 than you are replacing the next String too, which can be machine instruction or data or text.

I did a search for ".net exe file structure" to try to get a right direction for you.
Here are some results, you should read it:

[.NET Assembly File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly-format)

[Anatomy of a .NET Assembly – PE Headers](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-pe-headers/)

[The .NET File Format](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12585/The-NET-File-Format)

[What is the file structure of an .exe file? What is the memory location of its starting address?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-file-structure-of-an-exe-file-What-is-the-memory-location-of-its-starting-address)

Comment: thank you for your response and the file format links.  I've edited my question. My original question did read as though I wanted to add additional data expanding the file.  I agree that wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was way to simple.

Using Substring I subtracted the length of the searchString so I wouldn't overwrite the buffer.  Works great!

Ref: https://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

```
        string searchString = "YY";
        string replacementString = "ZZZ";

        string update = replacementString.Substring(0, searchString.Length);

        byte[] fileName = File.ReadAllBytes(@"testBin.exe"),
        oldBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(searchString),
        newBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(update);
```